# Textbox,Database,Gridview,Error or succes messages

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

if user inserted value in textbox present in database then show to gridview(display in grid view) else error message in c#..
If successfully found then show else show that data not found as you inserted in textbox.....Hlep me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRO7w.png)

Comment: The question asked is a little vague. Please can you state what the problem you are trying to solve is and what you have tried.

Comment: help in this code..

Comment: private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LoginSecurity;Integrated Security=True;");
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *From VehiclesInformation Where Vehicle_Number='" + vehicleNumberBox.Text + "'", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;       
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vehicleNumberBox.Text))
{
 displayMessage.Text = "Vehicle number need to be filled!!";
 displayMessage.ForeColor = Color.OrangeRed;
 }

Answer (score 6):

You could search the data from the **database** by the user inserted value on the **TextBox**. If you get the data from database than populate the data on grid otherwise show the **ErrorMessage/NotFound** that you want.

```
    string searchText = TextBox1.Text;
    var dbResponse = GetDataFromDB(searchText); // This method return data from database
    if(dbResponse != null)
    {
     // set value into grid
    }
    else
    {
    //Error Message or Not Found
    }
```

Comment: private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LoginSecurity;Integrated Security=True;");
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *From VehiclesInformation Where Vehicle_Number='" + vehicleNumberBox.Text + "'", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;       
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vehicleNumberBox.Text))
{
 displayMessage.Text = "Vehicle number need to be filled!!";
 displayMessage.ForeColor = Color.OrangeRed;
 }

Comment: this is mine code but i want to add intelligence in it so please dear.........

Comment: Please explain what kind of intelligence are you want?

Comment: Las problem solved Help to this new one..Dear ,
 Please Help me regard to my mentioned bellow problem as in C# Visual Studio.
When I login to form it show me you are login with admin or Client.
 
But when I go to next form and back to this form or main page again it show me you are login as Open .ChangePassword,Text:ChangePassword

Comment: Could you please provide the code?